# graphing of two realtions

Tags: relations, graphing-functions

We have the following relations:

$$S_1=\{(x,y) \in Z^2:x+y>1 \text{ and } x>0 \}$$

$$S_2=\{(x,y) \in P^2:x+y>1 \text{ and } x>0 \}$$

We have to make the graph for each occasion. My question is, what is the difference between these two graphs i am a little confused on how to graph them

Comment: You need to tell us what $P$ is. Positive integers?

Comment: is a projective space $P^2$

Comment: I'm more than a little confused. How are you defining $P^2$ that it would be natural to say $(x, y) \in P^2$? Standard definitions of $P^2$ have its elements as being equivalence classes of points in $\Bbb R^3$. So even if you meant a point in one of those classes, you are still a coordinate short. And how are you defining summation and order in this situation? The question doesn't make sense. Are your sure it is the projective plane?

Comment: if it is positive integers how we can graph these two occasions?